# History for this remote command => ssh username@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "echo foo"

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-12.04

## 2 Questions

1. In the following command, does `echo foo` get logged anywhere on an Ubuntu server?

   `# remote server us running Ubuntu 12.04

           $ ssh username@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "echo foo"`
2. If yes to #1, how do I find `echo foo` in the remote server's logs and/or history?

## Notes

- After running the command from question #1, when I SSH into the server, and run `history`, I don't see `echo foobar`in the history.  I can however see previous commands I typed in manually from the command line during previous remote login sessions.
- I also tried running these 3 commands:

  `$ ssh username@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "history > foo.txt"`

  `$ ssh username@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "echo foo; history > foo.txt"`

  `$ ssh username@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "echo foo && history > foo.txt"`

  In each case, `foo.txt` was just an empty text file.

Comment: I've wondered this myself and came to the same conclusion as you. It does not appear in the .bash_history of the user, at least. It would be good to confirm if it appears anywhere else, but I suspect not. AS for your comment on the 3 commands below, are you looking at foo.txt in the present working directory of your local host?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to #1: No: this is not logged anywhere by default on an Ubuntu 12.04 server.

*Additional note*: please read about the suggestion to install [snoopy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112686/log-ssh-activity)
on your Ubuntu server.